# In episode 4 of Golden Time is that the same Nana?

Tags: nana, golden-time

At 15:27 in episode 4 of Golden Time, is that Nana the same as one of the mains in NANA?

The girl was decked out in a punk rock outfit, lugged around a guitar and gave the characters tickets to a show she's performing at. She called herself Nana. I was wondering if it's supposed to be the same Nana as one of the mains in the NANA series?

[image: Nana]

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself

Comment: It has to be the same NaNa I mean they're way too similar to not be.

Comment: How would the timelines fit together between Golden Time and Nana?

Comment: I don't think there's enough context to establish *when* the cross-over took place, let alone if it *is* in fact a cross-over

Comment: I also notice in one of the episodes that Yana, with blonde hair, looks a little like Shizuo from Durarara!!

Answer (score 5):

Either inspired by or the same character, it seems. Nothing I'm seeing online gives her a name besides "NANA-sempai" in all capitals like the NANA manga.

Note: Romi Park voices the original Nana. The Nana in Golden Time is voiced by Satomi Satou.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it's a parody of the character, they look very similar (ignoring style differences) and share the same names (also in capitals like the manga/anime's title as mentioned in another answer) and are both punk/rock musicians.

[image]

Otherwise it's a large coincidence, but I would imagine it was intentional, as Nana is a very well known series.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like the character from Golden Time is copying NANA, because on wiki (Russian) it is said that Tada Banri read the NANA manga while hospitalized.

Comment: Do you have a link to that wiki page?

Comment: It's on the [Russian "Golden Time"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Time) page, but the editor didn't leave any notes to support their claims. You know, Wikipedia-style. But to be clear, it says that "Nana behaves like a character from the manga ̈„Nana“, that Banri was reading while at the hospital", so it's probably just an observation or sorts.

Answer (score 0):

It's meant as an Easter Egg and inside joke similar to Khoto Hirano in High School of the Dead having the name of the creator of Hellsing and the character acting and looking somewhat like Alucard in moments of extreme violence.

Within anime and other visual media there are references like these everywhere if you look for them.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought some of the characters were parodies in themselves. She is no exception.

Another example, which strikes resemblance in my opinion is "2D-Kun", who resembles Keima Katsuragi from "The World God Only Knows". Both only like fictional 2D characters and have similar appearances.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I also think it's interesting how Linda-Sempai's real name can be nicknamed Nana. That's what her brothers fiancé called her. And on some wiki pages, they actually refer to her as Nana.. not even Linda! Also Linda and Nana are close friends and are always in the apartment together. Another funny coincidence as well!!

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer